# Unable to decode url parameter in cakephp2

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When I use the following js code to transition. The url becomes `www.sample/school/search/?john%27s`. When I checked the following url's value , it is `www.sample/school/search/?john's`. I used decodeUri but ddidn't work. Should I change the settings in the cakephp2? All I want to do is the url's get parameter to have the apostrophe and not the %27. I searched around for clues but no solution. It would be great if you have some tips or examples. I woluld love to hear from you.

`location.href = this.action + '?' + query;` ← The query contains the value "John's" that I got from the text input. This link transitions to the School controllers search action.